# Updating d3 force directed graph links not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm trying to update my force directed graph, but only the nodes are updating (not the links). I'm basically trying to update the color of the links using a css class, but it doesn't get set. The update function is called whenever something gets updated.

My code is kind of complex, so I just pasted the gist of it:

```
let update = () => {

    // [...]
    // Update nodes and their css classes works perfectly
    
    // But updating link css class is not updating at all

    link = link
        .data(links)
        .join(enter => {
            return enter
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", d => {

                    return "someclass"; // <-- This is not constant!
                });
        },
            update => {
                return update
            }
        );

        this._simulation.nodes(nodes);
        this._simulation.force("link").links(links);
        this._simulation.alpha(1).restart();
};
```

Take particular note of the `return "someclass";` line. The returned string may change, but the class does not get applied.

Is there some obvious reason for this not working?

Using the following versions:

d3: 6.7.0, d3-force: 2.1.1

Comment: Your codes applies to the **enter** selection only... Unless there are new links entering via data-binding the `links` variable this will obviously not **update** any existing links. You need to move that code to the `update` callback.

Comment: If your class is not constant, how do you select your links before calling `links.data(...).enter(...)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Found out :)

Comment: @altocumulus thanks! i feel pretty stupid now